# rsync specific dirs to another exact same path as before

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, rsync

I want to rsync dirs includes **files** from path to another exact path that has been rsynced from it

For example :-

path 1 have

```
dir1/
dir1/mysql
dir1/log1
dir1/log2
dir1/log3
dir1/home
```

want to rsync **mysql** and **home** directories only but will be rsync with the same path name

so the result in the rsync place

```
dir1/
dir1/mysql
dir1/home
```

hope someone help me with the right rsync comand

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
rsync -av  origin/{home,mysql} destination/
```

Comment: what if home into another directory no mysql and home under same directory ? like dir1/dir2/home and mysql will be dir1/mysql

Comment: you can nest {d1,d2{dx,dy}} as you like. If things become too complex you can put directories in a text file and use `--files-from=whattorsync.list` or call `rsync` multiple times from a script.

Comment: sorry the main command you post didn't rsync the home and mysql directories

Comment: sorry, I assumed your shell is `bash`.